# Thymeleaf + CSS: flex-direction works differently in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, thymeleaf

I want to put html div's in this way:
[image: destination layout]

So, I want to have 3 main div's side by side. In the first one I need many div's (they are in `th:each`) and each of them is under the previous one.

But when I do it in Thymeleaf in my Spring app, it doesn't work. I seems as if `Card Images` inherit property flex-direction: row. As a result I get such layout:
[image: current layout]
Blue cards should be aligned in one column. 
Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head th:replace="fragments/header :: head"></head>

<body>

  <header class="superhead">
    Welcome in <span class="content-header">Notes-app</span>
  </header>

  <a href="/add">Add a note</a>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <div id="cards-wrapper" th:each="n : ${notes}" class="card-container">
      <div class="card" style="width:400px; margin: auto;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="polaroid_2X.png" width="150" height="150" alt="Card image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h4 class="card-title" th:text="${n.getNoteTitle()}"></h4>
          <p class="card-text" th:text="${n.getNoteContent()}"></p>
          <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>
            <form action="/edit" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" th:value="${n.getNoteTitle()}" name="noteTitle" />
              <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">Edit</button>
            </form>
            <form action="/delete" method="get">
              <input type="hidden" th:value="${n.getNoteTitle()}" name="delnote">
              <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: orange;">
      <h2>Create a note</h2>
    </div>


    <div style="background-color: yellow;">
      <h2>Find a note</h2>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I replace `th:each` with some `Cards`, All work fine. Why it doesn't work with `th:each`, how to fix it?

Comment: you should have place the `th:each` on the `.card` instead of the `.card-wrapper` I guess...

Comment: Compare the source in the browser without thymeleaf vs with it.  The differences should be easily visible, then fix the Thymeleaf so it looks the same.  It's not possible for Thymeleaf to be the culprit here.